# ${__time} function output is incorrect

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I'm trying to get today's date using time function of jmeter with the format "${__time(yyyy-MM-dd)}" in BeanShell postprocessor. But after executing the Beanshell postprocessor the result shows as "1996". Basically the "time" function is displaying result by subtracting the values like "2018-03-19"=1996.
Please help me to resolve this issue so that i can get current date and time.
Beanshell code as below

```
 import org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

String testPlanFile = GuiPackage.getInstance().getTestPlanFile();
String testPlanFileDir = FilenameUtils.getFullPathNoEndSeparator(testPlanFile);
vars.put("testPlanFileDir", testPlanFileDir);
//create the file in test plan file dir and print current time and Date

FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(testPlanFileDir+"/CurrentDate.txt", true);
PrintStream p = new PrintStream(f); 
this.interpreter.setOut(p); 
//current date and time;
print("Current date is:"+${__time(yyyy-MM-dd)});
f.close();
```

Comment: can you show your Beanshell code ?

Comment: I'm trying to save today's date in txt file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set time function call as parameter of your PreProcessor (**by the way migrate to JSR223 + Groovy** for performances)

And use it then with variable **Parameters**:

[image: Using Parameters in Groovy]

Answer (score 1):

Try this with **JSR223 PostProcessor** and language **Groovy** and put this into script area:

```
def a = new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd')
new File('Example.txt').withWriter('utf-8') { 
         writer -> writer.writeLine 'Current date is : ' + a.toString() }
```

(It works on **JMeter 4.0**)

Answer (score 0):

You should move to JSR223 postprocessor according to JMeter [Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting):

> Since JMeter 3.1, we advise switching from BeanShell to JSR223 Test Elements

Until then you can fix it by quoting the function call as

```
  print("Current date is:"+"${__time(yyyy-MM-dd)})";
```

This fix will treat the function's return value as string. 
Currenty it treat it as a numeric substraction: 2018-3-19=1996 and then convert it to string

Comment: Hi @user7294900, using ${} within JSR223 Test Element will trigger performance issues.

Comment: I wasn't sure about it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Performance anti-pattern #1: given you use [GuiPackage](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/gui/GuiPackage.html) class you won't be able to execute your test in [non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui), consider migrating to [FileServer](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/services/FileServer.html) instead
2. Performance anti-pattern #2: using Beanshell is not recommended as in case of high loads it might become the bottleneck. Since [JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) [and Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for any form of scripting
3. Performance anti-pattern #3: don't inline [JMeter Variables or Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) in script body they break Groovy compiled scripts caching function and might resolve into something which will cause unexpected behaviour (like in your case), compilation failure or even data loss.

So:

- Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) instead of the Beanshell one
- Put the following code into "Script" area:

  ```
  String testPlanDir = org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir()
  File currentDate = new File(testPlanDir + File.separator + "CurrentDate.txt") 
  currentDate << new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd")
  ```